# Persist default Cloudfront behavior cache policy on Amplify deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-amplify

I have a NextJS webapp on AWS Amplify where I need to forward the `Host` header to the Lambda function. I managed to do it by setting the cache policy of the default Cloudfront behavior to the `Amplify` managed cache policy, but each deployment reverts the default behavior to empty legacy cache settings

Is there a way to persist the default cache policy to a managed policy on deploy? Either on deployment or with a post-deploy script

Comment: i have this same problem but with response headers policy. Would be much more convenient to manage it directly at Cloudfront.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround which I described in detail here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/2622#issuecomment-1186611188

It relies on calling a post-deploy Amplify notification which updates the Cloudfront distribution through a Lambda function